# Unable to connect java client application to dockerize ignite server in windows 10

Tags: docker, ignite

I have been able to successfully run apache ignite with custom config using the command

```
docker run -it --net=host -v "pathToLocalDirectory"/config:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config -e "CONFIG_URI=file:///opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml"  apacheignite/ignite.
```

But when I run my java project in IntelliJ I get the message

"IP finder returned empty addresses list. Please check IP finder configuration and make sure multicast works on your network...".

Note: the java client project works if I run the ignite server using windows batch file.
Also, I have published 47500 port as well. the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

try running it using docker -run -it --net=host (don't mount the volumes).

If that doesn't work, it means that either something is incorrect w/your docker setup OR you are configuring discovery differently for clients and servers.

check the IP addresses listed in your client discovery section.

ssh into the container and check what is actually mounted?
run docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash

check: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml is there and contains the correct discovery info.

Check that the ignite log (located in /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work/log/) specifies that the correct config is being used.
It will have a line like so: [INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Config URL: file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml

If you don't see the mounted config file try mounting more simply.

docker run -d -v /local/dir/config.xml:/config-file.xml -e CONFIG_URI=/config-file.xml   apacheignite/ignite

more info: 
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/docker-deployment
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery